# Can i build a already local build mysql Database with the mysql Dockerfile?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

i am completely new to Docker and everything that has to do with it. In my last semester i build a mysql Database locally with mysql Workbench and connected a java project to it. This year i need to make this run in a Docker Container. I have pulled the Dockerfile from GitHub and i am using Portainer to manage Docker.

My teacher wants the following:
He wants me to put my code in a repository which he created for me
Then he wants to pull my project, which should include a Dockerfile, so that he don't needs to manually rebuild my mysql Database.

So how can i do this? Do i need to change the mysql Dockerfile? Or should i use the default one and then initialize my Database in my javacode?

This i my first post here on stackoverflow and i am not that advanced in programming (only 2 years experience with java), so if i can give you any more information please let me know. I hope this is the right way to post questions here.

I am thankful to everyone helping me out!

Greets, Luciore

Comment: Start with this tutorial [Customize your MySQL Database in Docker](https://medium.com/better-programming/customize-your-mysql-database-in-docker-723ffd59d8fb). You need to create an image derived from official mysql. Then add the sql scripts to initialize the database during container startup. It's all in the tutorial.

Comment: so basically this is working. Thanks for that. But when i execute my Docker Cointainer only the Database i wanted is there. The tables are not getting created. in my .sql file i have all statements to create the tables - what am i missing?

Comment: If you now have a [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ask another question or edit this one adding Dockerfile sql error and logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your `sql` file also on GitHub, and it should be accessible from your docker environment.

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order.
>   [docker-hub-mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

And yes, Also you need to modify your Dockerfile, Here is the example.

This will build mysql8 based docker image, will download `sql` file from GitHub and will initiate DB name `classicmodels` mean anything a valid SQL file will be executed on boot.

```
FROM mysql:8
RUN apt update && apt install curl -y
RUN curl -0 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Adiii717/doctor-demo-app/master/sample_database.sql > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sampledb.sql
```

Build the docker image

```
docker build -t mysql8 .
```

Run the docker container

```
docker run --rm --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -it mysql8
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your comment, can you have a look at my Dockerfile because i was trying to do exactly what the tutorial says, please view my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076413/dockerfile-does-not-create-tables-from-my-initialize-sql