# Dockerfile does not create tables from my initialize.sql

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I want to do this [customize-your-mysql-database-in-docker](https://medium.com/better-programming/customize-your-mysql-database-in-docker-723ffd59d8fb)

I get to the point where I execute the docker container and my database "studienarbeit" is shown to me. But when I use the command show tables it says to me that there are no tables in the database.

So I assume that there is something wrong with my Dockerfile or my initializeDB.sql?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mysql
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE studienarbeit
COPY ./sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**InitializeDB.sql:**

```
CREATE TABLE `buchausleihe` (
  `ausleihnummer` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Typ` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `personid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seriennummer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Ausleihdatum` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Rückgabedatum` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ausleihnummer_UNIQUE` (`ausleihnummer`),
  UNIQUE KEY `seriennummer_UNIQUE` (`seriennummer`),
  KEY `personid_idx` (`personid`),
  CONSTRAINT `personid` FOREIGN KEY (`personid`) REFERENCES `person` (`personid`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `seriennummer` FOREIGN KEY (`seriennummer`) REFERENCES `buchexemplar` (`seriennummer`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `buchexemplar` (
  `Seriennummer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Buchstatus` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `buchid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Seriennummer`),
  KEY `buchid_idx` (`buchid`),
  CONSTRAINT `buchid` FOREIGN KEY (`buchid`) REFERENCES `buchtyp` (`buchid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `buchtyp` (
  `Buchid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Autor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Titel` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Buchid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ISBN_UNIQUE` (`ISBN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `PersonID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Typ` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Vorname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Faku` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Matrikelnr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gruppe` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Straße` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hausnummer` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ort` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Plz` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PersonID_UNIQUE` (`PersonID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Matrikelnr_UNIQUE` (`Matrikelnr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Gruppe` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the docker, Your `SQL` file is not valid. you creating the table below at your file and referencing tables at the start of the script.

Checks the logs of your docker container.

[image]

```
use studienarbeit;
CREATE TABLE `buchtyp` (
  `Buchid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Autor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Titel` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Buchid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ISBN_UNIQUE` (`ISBN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `PersonID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Typ` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Vorname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Faku` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Matrikelnr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gruppe` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Straße` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hausnummer` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ort` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Plz` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PersonID_UNIQUE` (`PersonID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Matrikelnr_UNIQUE` (`Matrikelnr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Gruppe` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `buchexemplar` (
  `Seriennummer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Buchstatus` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `buchid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Seriennummer`),
  KEY `buchid_idx` (`buchid`),
  CONSTRAINT `buchid` FOREIGN KEY (`buchid`) REFERENCES `buchtyp` (`buchid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `buchausleihe` (
  `ausleihnummer` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Typ` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `personid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seriennummer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Ausleihdatum` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Rückgabedatum` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ausleihnummer_UNIQUE` (`ausleihnummer`),
  UNIQUE KEY `seriennummer_UNIQUE` (`seriennummer`),
  KEY `personid_idx` (`personid`),
  CONSTRAINT `personid` FOREIGN KEY (`personid`) REFERENCES `person` (`personid`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `seriennummer` FOREIGN KEY (`seriennummer`) REFERENCES `buchexemplar` (`seriennummer`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

[image]

Comment: you are a very nice person for helping me out! Made my Day! Finally its working - thank you really much (i made an export out of mySQL the second you answered and tried my Dockerfile again and boom - its working)

Comment: u can also accept the other as per your that question

Comment: i have one side question - if i connect to this database inside the docker container now and do some inserts with my java program and stop the container - does it commit those inserts and update them so that i see them if i start the container again?

Comment: I will recomend mouting just mount mysql direcotry then no worry about database single query lose